# Distribute iOS app without phone

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, software-distribution

I finished my cross platform (Xamarin) App for iPhone, tested on a real device (from friend) with Free Provisioning. Everything is fine.

Now I am ready to distribute in the App Store, so I paid for the Developer Program. But it's still pending, and now I have to give the iPhone back - so don't have device anymore.

My question, when my Developer Account is ready, is a real device needed to do the distribution in the AppStore, as I only need to make a final build (I guess .IPA I have to create, like .APK for Android), and then upload to the App Store site. Do I need a real device for it, or can Xcode (or Xamarin) make the package without a phone attached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **do not *need*** an iDevice for distribution / building.

But you *should* have a couple of iDevices available one way or the other to test your app. You should make tests in terms of functionality, usability, speed, etc. on real devices. The simulator simply does not suffice for "serious" apps.

Comment: As I mentioned, I tested on a real device. But when I will be able to distribute, I won't have the device anymore with me. But, as you wrote, it's not needed then? That is great news.
Let's wait if any objections arrive, otherwise I will accept this as answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can send an app to the App Store without have a real device, you only need to configure the provisioning profile like this.

[image]

So you need to select "Generic iOS Device" and you can do an "Archive", this options make a build ready to send.

[image]

And you can validate with iTunes Connect or send directly to the App Store if you have all information done.

[image]

EDIT: If you need to test the camera, accelerometer or a settings like Scanner or and update after you have distributed your app, you will need a phone, cheers :)

Comment: Thanks @Carlos, great info.